# Why doesn't Collection extend Cloneable and Serializable?

Tags: java, collections

In Java library, what is the reason that the `Collection` interface doesn't extend `Cloneable` and `Serializable` interfaces?

Comment: At a guess, because you're not really meant to use `Collection` directly, so there's no need to clone or serialize it.

Comment: "why the designers have chosen A over B" questions are *usually* not very suitable for SO [IMHO], since the answers are likely to be subjective and argumentive, try to reduce the scope of the question to something more specific, it will probably fit better (I think).

Comment: Also, the `Cloneable` interface is kind of broken.

Comment: Not all collections are cloneable or serializable. Some are proxies for something else like a table in a database or it is store on another host.

Comment: Shouldn't question be why Collection doesn't extend.. rather than implement..?

Comment: @MartinPrakash updated the question with word implement

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Collection` is an interface that specifies a group of objects known as *elements*. The details of how the group of elements is maintained is left up to the concrete implementations of `Collection`. For example, some `Collection` implementations like `List` allow duplicate elements whereas other implementations like `Set` don't. A lot of the `Collection` implementations have a public `clone` method. However, it does't really make sense to include it in all implementations of `Collection`. This is because `Collection` is an abstract representation. What matters is the implementation. The semantics and the implications of either cloning or serializing come into play when dealing with the *actual* implementation; that is, the concrete implementation should decide how it should be cloned or serialized, or even *if* it can be cloned or serialized. In some cases, depending on what the actual backing-implementation is, cloning and serialization may not make much sense. So mandating cloning and serialization in *all* implementations is actually less flexible and more restrictive. The specific implementation should make the decision as to whether it can be cloned or serialized.

Here's an [explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#5) from Oracle's documentation:

> Many Collection implementations (including all of the ones provided by
>   the JDK) will have a public clone method, but it would be mistake to
>   require it of all Collections. For example, what does it mean to clone
>   a Collection that's backed by a terabyte SQL database? Should the
>   method call cause the company to requisition a new disk farm? Similar
>   arguments hold for serializable.
>
> If the client doesn't know the actual type of a Collection, it's much
>   more flexible and less error prone to have the client decide what type
>   of Collection is desired, create an empty Collection of this type, and
>   use the addAll method to copy the elements of the original collection
>   into the new one.

Answer (score 8):

Because if it did, that would require all `Collection` implementations to be `Cloneable` and `Serializable`, which is more restrictive than needed. *Implementations* frequently also implement those interfaces, but it's not for the `Collection` interface to require it.

Comment: It does have multiple inheritance for interfaces.